# How to pass an argument from command to another command?

Tags: functions, arguments

From the package [Neotree](https://github.com/jaypei/emacs-neotree/), I want to bind a key, that moves to the upper directory.

The upper directory is always on the top with `.. (up a dir)`. So I go to the first line of the neotree buffer, and call `neotree-enter` to move to the upper directory. As a true Emacs'er, I figured out I need to modify it to my own preference.

So I created a function:

```
(defun neotree-go-to-upper-directory ()
    (interactive)
    (evil-goto-first-line)
    (neotree-enter)
)

(evil-define-key 'normal neotree-mode-map (kbd "h")'neotree-go-to-upper-directory)
```

After pressing <kbd>h</kbd> in NeoTree buffer, the cursor moves only to the
top. But nothing happens. Then I call <kbd>M-x</kbd> `neotree-enter`, but still
nothing happens.

When trace back into the source code of `neotree-enter` with <kbd>C-h f</kbd>
then following the link, it's defined as:

```
(defun neotree-enter (&optional arg)
    "NeoTree typical open event.
    ARG are the same as `neo-open-file'."
    (interactive "P")
    (neo-buffer--execute arg 'neo-open-file 'neo-open-dir))
```

So I modified my function with adding the arguments as parameters:

```
(defun neotree-go-to-upper-directory (arg)
    (interactive "P")
    (evil-goto-first-line)
    (neo-open-dir arg)
)
```

Re-evaluated and calling `neotree-go-to-upper-directory` again inside Neotree
buffer, but still nothing happens. Something I went wrong. But can anyone tell
me where my code went wrong? It would be appreciated.

**EDIT:** For clarifity, as Lawlist suggested, I'm interested in a neotree
solution. But some knowledge of Elisp would be also nice, because I'm struggling
to understand why the function works for Neotree as well, and not in my case.

I got an working answer below:

```
(defun neotree-go-to-upper-directory ()
    "Go to the parent directory in the NeoTree buffer."
    (interactive)
    (neotree-dir ".."))
```

But unfortunately, this is not always working and I can't figure out what the cause of this is.  For example, I enter a directory with `neotree-enter` and I want to call the function, then nothing will happen. It will be only working if I call `neotree-change-root-directory` then calling the function afterwards, it seems. And not when I do `neotree-enter`

Comment: If you compile your function with `M-u M-x compile-defun` once your function is called, you can follow the code execution inside the debugger. This might give you some insight as to what's going on, what code is run and which doesn't (but you think it should).

Comment: Are you more interested in a `neotree` solution, or do you just want to better understand *generally* how arguments work in conjunction with the output of previously called functions that are designed to return a result?  Not all arguments to functions can be functions -- in most cases, you call the function you want the value of first and store the result in a let-bound variable and pass that result to whatever function you want to call thereafter.

Comment: I think the title of this question is not very clear in its current state. You don't really want to know how to pass the argument, you want to know why it doesn't work. And, above that, you want to be able to step a directory up in `neotree` using a single command. Perhaps it would be more clear if you renamed it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another possible solution:

```el
(defun neotree-go-to-upper-directory ()
    (interactive)
    (evil-goto-first-line)
    (call-interactively #'neotree-enter))

(evil-define-key 'normal neotree-mode-map (kbd "h")'neotree-go-to-upper-directory)
```

`call-interactively` invokes the function exactly as it would have been with a keybinding, so it *should* work, in theory that is.

---

Okay, so the `.. (up a dir)` line is actually a [button](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Buttons.html), which temporarily overrides <kbd>RET</kbd> while the point is over it. In that light, the solution is:

```el
(defun neotree-go-to-upper-directory ()
    (interactive)
    (evil-goto-first-line)
    (call-interactively #'push-button))

(evil-define-key 'normal neotree-mode-map (kbd "h")'neotree-go-to-upper-directory)
```

Comment: I tried that also before. It moves the cursor indeed to the first line of the Neotree buffer, but it will not invoke the `neotree-enter`. Perhaps it's related with my configuration? I will try it soon with `emacs -Q` option.

Comment: I tested it with `emacs -Q` option, with only a empty Evil configuration and Neotree package. And your code snippet doesn't work. It will moves the cursor to the top, but it don't changes the directory.

Comment: @ReneFroger Interesting... I will take a look at this later.

Comment: @ReneFroger Ah. I see what's going on now. Please see my edit.

Comment: Nice... how could you find it out?! I never heard of the `push-button` feature. How did you solved it?

Comment: @ReneFroger Simply go to the first line and do `C-h` `k` `RET`.

Answer (score 1):

> From the package Neotree, I want to bind a key, that moves to the upper directory.

Here's what I came up with after a bit of exploration.

```el
(defun neotree-go-to-upper-directory ()
  "Go to the parent directory in the NeoTree buffer."
  (interactive)
  (neotree-dir ".."))
```

Please edit the question to make it clear if this is what you were looking for (see **@lawlists**'s comment above).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but unfortunately, your solution seems not working sometimes. For example, I enter a directory with `neotree-enter` and I want to call your function, then nothing will happen. It will be only working if I call `neotree-change-root-directory` then calling your function afterwards, it seems. And not when I do `neotree-enter`. And I will edit the question, thanks for the suggestion.